# Materialized View Redshift - Refresh Failing due to Schema Permissions Changing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

We have a materialized view in Redshift. There's a daily ETL process which loads data into the materialized view every morning. There's a stored procedure which is executed every morning to run the 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW..' command after the daily ETL process. Sometimes the stored procedure fails to execute this command due to a privilege failure "Update of materialized view XXXX failed DETAIL: Error occurred while trying to execute a query : permission denied for schema XXXX". Do the permissions on a Materialized View change when new data is fed into a materialized view?

Comment: Does your code drop the view/table by any chance? You might need to ```ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE``` for the user on schema/tables

Answer (score 0):

The user performing REFRESH should be owner of the view and also has SELECT privileges on underlying tables.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-refresh-sql-command.html

Also, you should add CREATE privileges on your schema since full refresh drops/creates temporary tables in the background.